# How to download xlsx file into R from iCloud

Tags: r, download, xlsx, icloud

Hello and thanks for your time.
I am trying to import an xlsx file from iCloud and nothing seems to work.
Using

```
download.file(url = origin_url
              ,destfile = "/path/to/the/File.xlsx"
              ,mode = "wb")
```

Creates File.xlsx, but size is 45K from original 210K.
origin_url is the full path to the iCloud directory (the link to share with full permissions)+the name of the original file.

```
origin_url <- paste("https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/03Etcetera4Q#Genial-IO", "/o_File.xlsx",sep="")
```

As a result console gives:

> probando la URL
> ...//www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/03Etcetera4Q#Genial-IO/o_File.xlsx
> Content type 'text/html' length 46562 bytes (45 KB)
> =====    downloaded 45 KB

Suspecting from the file (is it a real xlsx file?) I moved it to a google drive folder and did the next and worked like a charm:

```
googledrive::drive_auth(email = "associated_drive_account@gmail.com")

d1 <- drive_find(pattern = "o_File.xlsx",type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",verbose = TRUE)

meta <- drive_get(id = d1$id)[["drive_resource"]]

n_id <- paste("https://drive.google.com/open?id=",d1$id,sep = "")

meta_name <- paste("/path/to/the/",meta[[1]]$originalFilename,sep = "")

drive_download(file = as_id(n_id),overwrite = TRUE, path = meta_name)
# downloaded file 210KB <--- OK!!
rm(n_id,d1)

#reading 4 worksheets
data <- map(1:4,function(j){
read_excel(meta_name,col_names = TRUE,sheet = j,skip = ifelse(j == 4,0,1))})
```

So... file is Ok.
I'm very confused. Sometimes when trying to import csv or other files in different ways, I had to change a character at the end of the shared link from 0 to 1.

Note: I used the readxl and xlsx libraries. (GDrive = Ok, iCloud = NOk)

#### *I deeply appreciate your help*